# How to view cone of vision in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Is the view the cone of vision assigned to turtles somehow visually? I wish to determine the accuracy of   assignment of angle to turtle's cone of vision by viewing it.
Commands like watch or follow turtles don't seem to achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vision Cone Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library, shows one approach for doing this. It makes the turtles in the vision cone "light up" by changing color.

Another possibility would be to add a `cone` breed to your model with an appropriate turtle shape, and then position and size the cone turtle or turtles to indicate the location of another turtle's cone. You could even use `tie` so that the cone turtle(s) would move and turn along with the turtle it is tied to.

I say cone "turtle(s)" because if your vision cones always have the same view angle, you can make a turtle shape to match that angle. But if the view angle varies, you'll need two or more turtles, positioned and sized appropriately, to indicate the extent of the cone.

Comment: If you use the "cone turtle(s)" approach, you could make them partly transparent (see the stuff about RGBA in [the **Colors** section of the NetLogo Programming Guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors).)

Answer (score 2):

In netlogo3d the ride primitive works something like this.

If you simply want to know what patches the turtle "sees" than ask them to change color.

```
ask turtles
  [ ask patches in-cone 3 60
    [ set pcolor red ] ]
```

From the dictionary.
 http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/in-cone.html